# Kafka: creating stream from topic with values in separate columns

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I just connected my kafka to postgres with a postgres source connector. Now when i print the topic i get following output:

```
rowtime: 4/1/20 4:16:12 PM UTC, key: <null>, value: {"userid": 4, "id": 5, "title": "lorem", "body": "dolor sit amet, consectetur"}
rowtime: 4/1/20 4:16:12 PM UTC, key: <null>, value: {"userid": 5, "id": 6, "title": "ipsum", "body": "cupidatat non proident"}
```

How do i make a stream from this topic so the values would be separated to their own columns as they were in the database table originally?

Bonus question: Is there any way to specify in jdbc-connector to separate the columns into the topic when creating source connector?

My connector looks like this:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "name": "jdbc_source_postgres_02",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/kafka",
                "connection.user": "bob",
                "connection.password": "builder",
                "topic.prefix": "post_",
                "mode":"bulk",
                "table.whitelist" : "kafka_t.users_t",
                "poll.interval.ms" : 500
                }
        }'
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "separated to their own columns"? You're showing a deserialised message (from ksqlDB from the looks of it). If you're using Avro from the source connector then the schema already exists with distinct columns

Comment: I edited how i set up the connector. I havent touched anything Avro. My end goal is to create table in ksqldb with column userid, id, title, body from this topic so i can later on sink that elsewhere

Comment: Can you include the config for your Kafka Connect worker?

Answer (score 1):

> How do i make a stream from this topic so the values would be separated to their own columns as they were in the database table originally?

Not 100% sure what you mean by this. If you use Kafka Streams, you can for example create a `KStream<KeyType, Columns>` with a custom `Columns` type (or just use JSON as value type) to get an "column view" on your data.

Similarly, you could use ksqlDB with a `CREATE STREAM` command -- it can automatically parse the JSON value into corresponding columns.

> Bonus question: Is there any way to specify in jdbc-connector to separate the columns into the topic when creating source connector?

What do you mean by that? Kafka topic have a key-value data model, and thus if you store any data in a topic, it must either go into the key or the value. If you have a more structured type, like a DB tuple, there is no native support in the Kafka brokers but you need to fit it into the key-value model.

Comment: Yes actually what i want to do is to make stream with `CREATE STREAM` command that would separate the columns from the topics value field into corresponding columns in stream. I got stuck at that because after `CREATE STREAM` I couldnt query anything from the strem so i thought to troubleshoot it from the topic @Matthias J. Sax

Comment: `I couldnt query anything from the strem` --- maybe inspect the kslqDB server logs to see why you don't get data -- IIRC, corrupted rows would be dropped and double check if your `CREATE STREAM` statement defines the correct names and datatype according to the JSON data in the value.

Comment: I actually got this fixed through another problem. Thank you for your ansers!